# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html issue

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to set the following item in my constants file:

```
define("ROOT", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/");
define("IMAGES", ROOT . "images/");
define("MAIN_CSS", ROOT . "css/");
define("MAIN_JS", ROOT . "js/");
define("PAGE_CSS", ROOT . "pages/css/"); 
define("PAGE_JS", ROOT . "pages/js/");
```

However when I go to use one of these for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo MAIN_JS; ?>includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

I'm getting this error message (domain.co.uk is my url which i don't want to display at the moment. NOT LIVE YET.)

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://domain.co.uk/home/ud2kbfbz/www/app/js/includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css".

It should really be displaying like the following:

```
http://domain.co.uk/home/ud2kbfbz/www/app/js/includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

I could do with some advise on this and some help in the right direction.

Comment: Using `DOCUMENT_ROOT` in a URL doesn't make any sense since it's the path on the server's file system..

Comment: Where's the difference between the two strings?

Comment: adding type="text/css" to the <link>?

Comment: Maybe .htaccess or the stylesheet is not found and server is returning an HTML error page.  What happens if you paste that URL into the browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you were to view the url you see in the error message you would most likely find a 404 error page.  It is an HTML resource.

Jon's comment is correct - using DOCUMENT_ROOT in a URL doesn't make sense.  Find a different way to reference your files as URLs.

Personally, in a framework I work with, it has a single front controller located at the url root at index.php.   it utilizes a function to figure out what the url base root is so that even if it's running in a sub folder it still works.

```
function current_base_url_path( $returnSingleSlash = false )
{
    list( $base_url_path ) = explode( '/index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] );
    $out = trim( $base_url_path, '/' ) . '/';

    if ( $out == '/' && $returnSingleSlash == false )
    {
        $out = '';
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
define("ROOT", 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```